# Sencha: How to break out of Ext.each

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

Can anyone show me how to break out of a Sencha Ext.each loop?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

found my own answer if you return false, it will not do the next iteration on the loop.

```
Ext.each(arrayObj, function(obj){
    if(obj.isSomethingTrue()){
        doSomething();
        return false; /*this will prevent each from looking at 
                        the next obj in the arrayObj*/
    }
});
```